# Deactivate the hover effect of products and leave the "quantity" and "buy" buttons always visible

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’m using the Shop Konado theme. 
I'm trying to disable the hover effect of the products and leave the "buy" button always visible in the mobile version: https://prnt.sc/t2ul5l (print from my store). Another example: https://prnt.sc/luen4q

I tried to use the following code in the additional Wordpress css:

```
html .shop-item:hover .shop-item-image:after {
    background: none;
}
```

But it did not work.

This is my store:
https://www.arteverdeagro.com.br/loja/product-category/todos-os-produtos-in-natura/

thanks for the help

Comment: it seems to me that in the mobile version it already works. it's not true?
i see this: https://imgur.com/Uze1OvI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
.box-hover{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    margin-top:10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!
How do I leave this to the mobile version only?

Comment: wrap it in a media query: `@media screen (max-width: 500px) { //put code here }`